# Java Persistence API in servlets

Tags: java, api, jsp, servlets, persistence

I am creating an entity class from a database and I want to excess the entity from the servlet. I wrote the following code:

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

        EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UniAppPU"); 
        EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager(); 
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Uniuser.findByUsername"); 
        query.setParameter("Username","clayd"); 
        List<Uniuser> result = query.getResultList(); 

        out.println("<p>" + result.size() + "</p>"); 

        em.close(); 

    }
}
```

I have a simple html page where the form action is being sent to this servlet.

```
    <form method="post" action="processLogin">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in">

    </form>
```

and this is the post:

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
}
```

The persistence xml file is the following:

```
<persistence-unit name="UniversityApplicationPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>UniversityEntity</jta-data-source>
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
<properties/>
```

This is not working while no errors are being shown. Do you have any ideas what is wrong please? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are many definitions of "not working". Which one are you referring to?

Comment: The servlet code to fetch data from the database. It is supposed to show how many records there are in the table but nothing is shown.

Comment: are you swallowing any exception, may be or may be your view is simply hiding that part check raw html

Comment: No errors, no exceptions just a blank page.

Comment: What request are you making and what url is your servlet mapped to?

Comment: the request is post. In which sense the mapping of the servlet please?

Comment: A `Serlvet` can only serve a request if it is registered with the servlet container with some `url-pattern` to handle. Also show your full class declaration. Where is the `doPost()`? What calls your `processRequest()` method?

Comment: You should edit your question instead. Also, we need to see your class that contains the method you're showing us and we need to see your deployment descriptor.

Comment: Please show us your deployment descriptor (web.xml).

Comment: I ask for web.xml and you show us the persistence.xml...

Answer (score 0):

This code is missing something like ..

First you are using wrong persistence unit name. Use this

EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UniversityApplicationPU");

Second you need to start the transaction before any fetching/updating. Your actual code will look like this.

```
    EntityManagerFactory emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("UniversityApplicationPU"); 
    EntityManager em = emFactory.createEntityManager(); 
    em.getTransaction.begin();
    Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Uniuser.findByUsername"); 
    query.setParameter("Username","clayd"); 
    List<Uniuser> result = query.getResultList(); 
    out.println("<p>" + result.size() + "</p>"); 
    em.close();
    emFactory.close();
```

Hope this will work.